# Splash Window does not appear - Swing

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

I have a splash screen for my swing application and wrote the below manifest file. I placed the png file that splash window should show into a directory named resources under the class that is being executed first (i.e.  /se/bookingapp/UI/resources/LOADLOGO.png). When I run the program in netbeans, the splash screen appears but when I double click on the built jar file and run it manually, the program starts without the splash screen. Do you know what i am missing?

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
    Created-By: 1.6.0_14-b08 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
    SplashScreen-Image: /se/bookingapp/UI/resources/LOADLOGO.png
    Main-Class: se.bookingapp.UI.MainFrame
```

Comment: have you tried running your application from console? `java -jar jarFileName.jar`

Comment: Things work in netbeans because I make the following VM setting in run properties:
-splash:resources/LOADLOGO.png
Do you know how I can do this automatically when double clicked on the jar file. The target user group of my application cannot run the application from the command console (they probably dont even know what command console is :(  )

Besides this, I tried running the jar file in command console. It still does not work.

Comment: It would be better if you could share a picture of file hierarchy. Seems like something is wrong there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments:

> Things work in netbeans because I make the following VM setting in run properties: -splash:resources/LOADLOGO.png

Change manifest file following way:

```
SplashScreen-Image: resources/LOADLOGO.png
```

Comment: Your last comment indeed helped. However, now when the splash screen disappears, the main program GUI looks minimized in the status bar in windows and it is not brought front by windows for the user to see it. Do you know why it's like this?

Comment: may be you can post another question, with little more hints. Your ui might be need to set the window state.

share some code snippet please.

Comment: I wrote no code for this spöash screen. all I did was to add a simple png file via this manifest file. Thanks for your earlier answer.

Comment: if you are trying to maximize your UI, try setting `setExtendedState(true)`. This is all i can help without any clue.